# Create a read-only file in yocto

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

How do I create a read-only file in yocto.

I have given only read permissions to all groups in the bbappend file

```
do_install_append() {
    install -m 0444 os-release ${D}${sysconfdir}/
}
```

ls -al /etc/os-release correctly list the permissions, but I am able to modify the file in root user.

How can I avoid this behavior and make it read-only

Comment: you have to create a read-only rootfs, root user on unix systems is special and it can do anything with the files unless you are booted using read-only rootfs.

Comment: But I don't see the similar behavior on Ubuntu, once i set the read permissions to all groups, root user is also unable to modify the file in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on ubuntu 18.04:

```
erni@Sally:~$ date >> test.txt
erni@Sally:~$ echo test >> test.txt
erni@Sally:~$ chmod 444 test.txt 
erni@Sally:~$ echo test2 >> test.txt
bash: test.txt: Permission denied
erni@Sally:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo test3 >> test.txt'
erni@Sally:~$ cat test.txt 
gio  6 dic 2018, 17.28.42, CET
test
test3
```

As you can see you can still modify a protected file in ubuntu